# I'm having trouble connecting to my private RDS instance to create a new db instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, amazon-rds

My webpage support multiple webpage instances, and each one of them holds an rds instance in aws. Currently I have 3 rds instances, but I just found out that you can have one rds with multiple db instances using the CREATE DATABASE command.

Because the rds is private, I followed the instructions on aws page to create an ec2 instance to connect to my private rds instance (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ec2-bastion-host). I can connect to the ec2 from my computer, but when I run any command, I dont get anything in return, i.e: aws rds describe-db-instances

Anybody have an idea of what could be wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: The awscli command `aws rds describe-db-instances` won't help you connect to an RDS instance, nor is its success or failure in any way helpful to you actually gaining access to the database from a SQL client (if that's what you're trying to do). Your RDS database needs to allow inbound connections on the relevant port number from the EC2 instance.